# optimization of normalized quadratic function

Tags: optimization

I'm a computer science student. Please I need a help in solving a constrained normalized quadratic function. I'm familiar with solving quadratic constrained optimization function with matlab by providing a symmetric matrix and a vector as inputs for quadprog matlab function. Now, I encountered an other form of quadratic function described as follows:

$$ \min_{0 \leq \alpha \leq C} \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{\alpha^tB\alpha}{\alpha1_N}+ b^t\alpha \right)$$

I don't know how I can deal with such function. Can I rewrite the normalized quadratic function as a quadratic function? Is there any tutorial describing the different mathematical steps for solving such problem in order to make the necessary implementation.

thanks.

Comment: What you mean by $\alpha1_N$ ?

Comment: In fact, $ b^t=\left[b_1,...,b_N\right] $ is a parameter vector. $B=\left[b_{ij}\right] $ is a symmetric matrix of parameters. $ \alpha 1_N $ denotes the product of the vectors of alpha by the vector of ones (with size $N$). i.e $ \alpha 1_N = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i $. $C$ is a  parameter.

Comment: you mean $0<=\|\alpha\|<=C$

Comment: $0 \leq \alpha  \leq C $  mean that  $ \forall i \in {1,...,N}, \quad 0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C $.

Answer (score 0):

This is rectangle constrained optimization problem. First solve the unconstrained problem, then check is the constraints are fullfield if not then solve the problem on each edge of the contrains ($\alpha_i = C$,  $\alpha_i = 0$), and choose the minimum.

Solving the unconstrained problem:
\begin{equation}
f(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha^T B\alpha}{2\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\alpha_i}}+b^T\alpha
\end{equation}
This is looks very similar to quadratic problem, but it is some kind of rational function. Therefore I would just use an iterative method.

\begin{equation}
\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n+\gamma d\alpha
\end{equation}

You can use gradient-desent it is the most simple to perform but it is the most slow solution. I would suggest Newton's method, and find $d\alpha$ from:

\begin{equation}
Hf(\alpha)d\alpha=\nabla f(\alpha)
\end{equation}

I didn't check this but i think that in this case the hessian matrix will be positive definite, and allow you to find $d\alpha$ by using the cholesky decomposition.